# How does the agents.volumes parameter supposed to work in Datadog Helm Chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, datadog

I'm attempting to mount a filepath into my datadog agent container, which is being provisioned into a kubernetes cluster via [Datadog Helm Chart.](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/datadog/datadog)

I'm using `agents.volumes` value to pass in. which the docs describe as "Specify additional volumes to mount in the dd-agent container".

Based on the syntax found in the [Datadog/helm-charts repo](https://github.com/DataDog/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/datadog/values.yaml#L1151-L1156) - I'm using:

```
  agents:
    volumes:
      - hostPath:
          path: /var/log/cloud-init.log
        name: cloud-init
```

But when I apply that change to my cluster, I don't see any evidence that this path has been mounted anywhere on my agent container. I'm not seeing any great explanation of mount a volume from my host container into the datadog agent container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that value is only used to declare the volumes on the DaemonSet pod definition, not to mount them.

`agents.volumes` is for defining custom volumes on the agent but this is used on the DaemonSet definition, specifically on `spec.template.spec.volumes` [look here](https://github.com/DataDog/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/datadog/templates/daemonset.yaml#L154-L156).

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: {{ template "datadog.fullname" . }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  ...
spec:
    ...
    spec:
      ...
      volumes:
      ...
{{- if .Values.agents.volumes }}
{{ toYaml .Values.agents.volumes | indent 6 }}
{{- end }}
```

To actually use those volumes you have to define  the variable [`agents.volumeMounts`](https://github.com/DataDog/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/datadog/values.yaml#L1165-L1168) which is used [here](https://github.com/DataDog/helm-charts/blob/4c1b07ea55833e40b3bfce45dd774edfdbf126ce/charts/datadog/templates/_container-agent.yaml#L190-L192).

```
{{- define "container-agent" -}}
- name: agent
  image: "{{ include "image-path" (dict "root" .Values "image" .Values.agents.image) }}"
  ...
  volumeMounts:
    ...
{{- if .Values.agents.volumeMounts }}
{{ toYaml .Values.agents.volumeMounts | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
...
{{- end -}}
```

So you most likely want to define your values like this:

```
agents:
  volumes:
    - hostPath:
        path: /var/log/cloud-init.log
      name: cloud-init
  volumeMounts:
    - name: cloud-init
      mountPath: /some/path
      readOnly: true
```